# Cannot convert IQueryable to ObjectSet

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

In my C# class i have a following code:

```
var myData= Db.SetName;
myData = myData.Where(p => p.Set2.Date >= start
                && p.Set2.Date <= end);
```

Which Db is my DbObject( Or DbContext)

But i Get following error:

```
Error:Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable<SetName>' to 
'System.Data.Objects.ObjectSet<SetName>'. An explicit conversion exists 
(are you missing a cast?)
```

Where is the problem?

Comment: Is it a line after the `Where` which is throwing the error? If so please include that line in your question.

Comment: no, you assume there is no code. feel free and remove comment blow that.

Comment: So it's the `Where` line which is throwing the error - is it a compile-time or run-time error?

Comment: Also is this the only code required to get the error? Because the `myData.Where()` line doesn't do anything by itself.

Comment: I removed additional comment's. It is compile error. The error is by `myData.Where()`!

Comment: Try `myData.Where(p => p.Set2.Date >= start && p.Set2.Date <= end).AsQueryable()`?

Comment: I am sorry i just edited my code. Look at this section: `myData = myData.Where()`. The error is by this!

Comment: @chridam I got same error.

Comment: Is there any performance problem if i change my first line code to : `var myData= Db.SetName.AsQueryable();` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This line:

```
var myData = Db.SetName;
```

Creates and assigns a variable named `myData` of type `ObjectSet<SetName>`. The following line:

```
myData = myData.Where(p => p.Set2.Date >= start && p.Set2.Date <= end);
```

...attempts to assign a value of type `IQueryable<SetName>` to the same variable. Although `ObjectSet<SetName>` implements `IQueryable<SetName>`, you can't assign a value of the  latter type to a variable of the former type for the same reason you can't assign a value of type `IAnimal` to a variable of type `Dog`.

The underlying issue is (kind of) the use of `var`, because that's hiding the type of `myData` and obscuring the reason for the error. This should work:

```
IQueryable<SetName> myData = Db.SetName;
myData = myData.Where(p => p.Set2.Date >= start && p.Set2.Date <= end);
```

...as should this:

```
var myData = (IQueryable<SetName>)Db.SetName;
myData = myData.Where(p => p.Set2.Date >= start && p.Set2.Date <= end);
```

...because both explicitly state that `myData` is of type `IQueryable<SetName>`, and therefore assignable later to a value of that type.

Comment: Steve, I have a question: in `var myData =(IQueryable<SetName>)Db.SetName;` is myData stores whole `SetName` records from the database?

Comment: That doesn't get all the database records, no. All it does it tell the compiler that `myData` is going to use `Db.SetName` through its implementation of the `IQueryable<SetName>` interface.

Answer (score 2):

You are implicitly declaring `myData` as one type and then trying to assign its value to another type.  Do this instead:

`var myData= Db.SetName.Where(p => p.Set2.Date >= start
                && p.Set2.Date <= end).AsQueryable();`

Comment: I know this. But i want add filter later to my data by Where `Clause`. I have some textbox in my page and i want to filter based on these textboxes. Do you have any other idea?

Comment: LINQ queries work on any IEnumerable, so you should be able to query on it just fine.  Have you verified that you cannot?

Comment: I updated my answer.  Adding the `.AsQueryable()` *should* fix it, although I can't say for sure since I can't actually test it myself.

Comment: No, it is not correct. The correct answer is that i should add AsQueryable function to end of Setname. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about it, 'cause I'm not in my machine, but you can append `.AsQueriable()` after the `Where()` and you are good to go.